# Use of sort command with 3 colums

Tags: bash

I am trying to sort the following text:

```
Tue 2014 Nov 25 07:44:44 berlin VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 08:01:12 paris VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 08:44:45 berlin VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:01:18 paris VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:12:52 london VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:44:45 berlin VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 10:44:50 berlin VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 10:57:34 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:35:56 london VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:47:05 amsterdam VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:57:34 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 12:47:06 amsterdam VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 12:57:33 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 13:47:06 amsterdam VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 13:57:33 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 14:47:07 amsterdam VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 14:57:33 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:14:07 london VPN connection disconnected
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:35:05 paris VPN connection disconnected
Tue 2014 Nov 25 10:57:26 amsterdam VPN connection disconnected
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:35:41 berlin VPN connection disconnected
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:39:00 london VPN connection disconnected
```

I want to sort on 2 criteria:
1. First sort on the 6th column (city name)
2. Then sort on the time (5th column)

The text came from a file called text.txt which I use the cat command.

I use the following command:

```
cat text.txt | sort -k6 -k5,1n
```

However it produces the following output ( it does sort on city name but not on time field) :

```
Tue 2014 Nov 25 10:57:26 amsterdam VPN connection disconnected
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:47:05 amsterdam VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 12:47:06 amsterdam VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 13:47:06 amsterdam VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 14:47:07 amsterdam VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:35:41 berlin VPN connection disconnected
Tue 2014 Nov 25 07:44:44 berlin VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 08:44:45 berlin VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:44:45 berlin VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 10:44:50 berlin VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 10:57:34 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:57:34 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 12:57:33 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 13:57:33 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 14:57:33 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:14:07 london VPN connection disconnected
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:39:00 london VPN connection disconnected
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:12:52 london VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:35:56 london VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:35:05 paris VPN connection disconnected
Tue 2014 Nov 25 08:01:12 paris VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:01:18 paris VPN connection succeed
```

How do I solve this problem so I can sort the text on 1. city name, then on the time field?

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your `sort`. This one works:

```
sort -k6,6 file
Tue 2014 Nov 25 10:57:26 amsterdam VPN connection disconnected
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:47:05 amsterdam VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 12:47:06 amsterdam VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 13:47:06 amsterdam VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 14:47:07 amsterdam VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 07:44:44 berlin VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 08:44:45 berlin VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:44:45 berlin VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 10:44:50 berlin VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:35:41 berlin VPN connection disconnected
Tue 2014 Nov 25 10:57:34 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:57:34 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 12:57:33 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 13:57:33 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 14:57:33 dallas VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:12:52 london VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:14:07 london VPN connection disconnected
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:35:56 london VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 11:39:00 london VPN connection disconnected
Tue 2014 Nov 25 08:01:12 paris VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:01:18 paris VPN connection succeed
Tue 2014 Nov 25 09:35:05 paris VPN connection disconnected
```

This works because your timestamps are using `HH:MM:SS` format.

Comment: I was going to post `sort -k6,6 -k5,5 file` command first then realized it works without `-k5,5` also. Reason I believe is that timestamps are using `HH:MM:SS` format and natural ordering of those values is good enough to give us sorted values.

Comment: Why did you edit the OP's _output_? He originally posted _incorrect_ results and stated that it was incorrect. You have changed it to his _expected_ results, without changing his statement to correspond...

Comment: @DenhamCoote: Damn, my mistake, that was a bad copy/paste mistake as OP had lots of `<br>` and I was trying to remove them from unix script. Let me correct it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `sort -k 6`, it sorts on on field 6, then 7, 8, 9 etc. From the manual:

> KEYDEF  is  F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position,
>   where F is a field number and C a character position in the field;
>   both are origin 1, and the **stop position defaults to the line's
>   end**.

If you want to sort on just field 6, set it explicitly as start and stop field:

```
sort -k 6,6
```

If you want to sort on 6, then 5, do this:

```
sort -k 6,6 -k 5,5
```